# Proof of existence of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying for my Linear Algebra final and I'm having some issues with this proof:

If $T\colon S \to V$ is a linear transformation such that all the non-zero elements of $S$ are eigenvectors, prove that there is a scalar $c$ such that $T(x) = cx$.

I'd appreciate any help you care to offer.

Comment: Do you mean that there exists $c$ such that, forall $x\in S$ it is true that $T(x)=cx$?

Comment: @GitGud No, the assumption is that $T(v)=c_vv$ for all $v$, where the constant possibly depends on $v$.

Comment: @Potato There's something I'm not understanding. That's an imediate consequence of the definition of eigenpair.

Comment: @GitGud We need to show that the constant is independent of $v$.

Comment: @Potato Then I claim that's exactly what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @GitGud It's not entirely clear to me what you mean, but you should write up an answer!

Comment: @Potato my interpretation of the problem is the following: Let $S$ be a vector space over $\mathbb F$. If $T\colon S\to V$ is a linear transformation such that all the non-zero elements of $S$ are eigenvectors, then $$\exists c\in \mathbb F\forall x\in S(T(x)=cx).$$ But this is false for $T(x)=\text{diag}(1,2)x$, for all $x\in S$, where $S=V=\mathbb R^{2\times 1}$.

Comment: @GitGud That isn't a counterexample. If $a$ and $b$ are the basis elements (eigenvectors) in your example, consider $a+b$. It's not an eigenvector, so not all elements of $S$ are eigenvectors.

Comment: @Potato I realise now what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ be a basis, or any lin. independent set, of $\;V\;$ , then

$$Tv_i=c_iv_i\;,\;\;c_i\in\Bbb F\;$$

But also $\;v_i+v_j\;,\;\;i\neq j\;$ ,
 is an eigenvector  so

$$c_iv_i+c_jv_j=T(v_i+v_j)=c_{i+j}(v_i+v_j)$$

Since the pair $\;\{v_i,v_j\}\;$ is linearly independent, it **must** be that $\;c_i=c_j=c_{i+j}$ . End now the argument.

Answer (score 2):

We know that for every $v\in S$, $Tv=c_vv$, where $c_v$ is some constant possibly depending on $v$. We want to show that $c_v=c_w$ for all nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$. It suffices to assume that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent (if $w=av$, then clearly we must have $c_w=c_v$). For all such vectors

$$c_vv+c_ww=T(v+w)=c_{v+w}v+c_{v+w}w.$$

Rearranging,

$$(c_v-c_{v+w})v=-(c_w-c_{v+w})w.$$

If either of the coefficients is zero, it's easy to see that $c_v=c_w=c_{v+w}$. Otherwise, dividing shows that $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent, a contradiction.